# How To Upgrade HAProxy On Debian VM?

Tags: debian, haproxy

Does someone have clear instructions for upgrading HAProxy to the latest stable release?

We're presently using 1.8.19 on a Debian VM and need to upgrade it to 2.1.3.

I came across the following instructions: https://blog.geralexgr.com/linux/upgrade-haproxy-to-2-1-3-red-hat-enterprise-linux-server-centos

However, they really aren't clear for someone who's never done this before. I don't want to be compiling source code unless I absolutely have to.

Running *apt-get install haproxy* says I'm on the latest version. Why then do I see 2.1.3 as the latest stable release?

Any help would be appreciated, as always!

Comment: FYI - This should be posted to SuperUser, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the current stable release is version 2.4, you can get the binary to install it via apt from [haproxy.debian.net](https://haproxy.debian.net).

Also, you can install the previous versions of haproxy like, 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3.

Comment: Thanks! That resolved the issue for me.